# Is serial voting an infraction or anything?

Tags: discussion, voting

[Chemus](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/users/23650/chemus) was kind enough to go through and fix broken links in many questions and answers—lots of them mine—on May 11, 2017, and at least one user upvoted some of those questions and answers—again, lots of them mine. I awoke May 12 to Voting Corrected, having lost about half of yesterday's rep.

Should I be concerned? Is this a black mark on me, on Chemus (who took on a task that I found overwhelming), or on the user who thought *Wow, there are a lot of useful questions and answers from that Chan guy that I missed before* and upvoted my questions and answers that all happened to pop up in a row?

Please note that my loss of rep points *really* isn't the issue. I just don't want suffering to ensue because of a good deed.

Comment: Is it possible the Voting Corrected thing happened automatically?

Comment: @markovchain O, I'm almost certain it did occur automagically, that it's just an algorithm or whatever. But I want to make sure it was just fluky and didn't actually reflect on those involved.

Comment: Where I live, which is in the same time zone as where you say you live, it's still the twelfth day of May...  Are you posting from the future? D:

Comment: @thedarkwanderer I'm not yet posting from the future, but if everything goes as planned I will be yesterday.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a serial voting FAQ available on Meta Stack Exchange: [What is serial voting and how does it affect me?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/126829/152515)

**Nobody is in trouble. There are no black marks as a result of this.** You and the user whose votes were reversed don't have to worry about any harm coming to yourselves or each other.

This appears to just be an automatic voting reversal because someone gave you a lot of votes in a short period of time. I'm surprised the algorithms got tripped, and if I had a say I would've un-tripped them, but at least there's no serious harm. This was just an automated system that roots out voting fraud getting a false positive.

Comment: Okay. Cool. Thank you very much for the speedy answer. Is it policy that a newly elected moderator change his or her profile picture or is that just a thing you do?

Comment: @HeyICanChan That is just a thing I do from time to time. I got to discussing Steven Universe with someone and and decided to change my avatar to a Diamond. `:D`

Comment: Understood. *SU*'s awesome: "If every pork chop were perfect we'd never have hot dogs."

Comment: If you want to join me in chat anytime I will happily rave about how wonderful it is. :)

Comment: Out of curiosity. Say the avid voter earned a badge like Vox Populi due to their voting patterns: when the votes are undone, is the badge lost? I know badges aren't revoked in general, but this seems like a special case, and I'm just wondering.

Comment: @markovchain I don't really know. I agree this seems like just the kind of special case that might prompt badge revocation. Might be a good question for [meta.se].